# Who can decide what fields are legitimate study fields?

Tags: legal

Who can decide what fields are legitimate study fields (in institutionalized schooling that is)?

Obviously legislature affects this, but how can one understand, whether those doing legislating understand the subject domains and their usefulness enough?

Can people be let to decide for themselves? Why, why not?

Comment: Those things are not "decided", they form and labels are attached later, at that point enthusiasts lobby to get them institutionalized. So it is done through social negotiation and action. "Data science" is getting institutionalized right now.

Comment: Great question. I only know that it's not me, otherwise the curriculum would look very different.